# Active admin customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an `Event` model with field status, which is string so it appears as a `text_field`. But I have a list of possible statuses and I want to display it as a `select` box. Also, when I select `cancel` status for a event it should ask me for the cancellation reason. I am not able to find good tutorial for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ActiveAdmin uses Formtastic for form generation, so [Formtastic's documentation](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) should answer your questions.

You can get a select instead of a textfield with the following code:

```
form do |f|
  f.status, :as => :select, :collection => STATUSES #whatever collection you want to display
end
```

Triggering an event when selecting "cancelled" should be solved with javascript.

Answer (score 55):

**Following is the example almost all customizations :)**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
  #Menu display index
  menu :priority => 1

  #Scopes
  scope :all
  scope :pending
  scope :approved
  scope :rejected
  scope :cancelled
  scope :featured

  #Filters  
  filter :city
  filter :user, :content_columns => :first_name
  filter :name
  filter :featured
  filter :location
  filter :details
  filter :start_datetime
  filter :end_datetime

  # New/Edit forms  
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :status, :label => "Event Status", :as => :select, :collection => Event::EVENT_STATUSES
      # Conditional show/hide using js
      cancel_reason_style = f.object.cancelled? ? "display:block" : "display:none"
      reject_reason_style = f.object.rejected? ? "display:block" : "display:none"
      f.input :reject_reason, :wrapper_html => {:style => reject_reason_style}, :hint => "Required if status event rejected"
      f.input :cancel_reason, :wrapper_html => {:style => cancel_reason_style}, :hint => "Required if status event rejected"
      f.input :city, :label => "Event Status"
      f.input :name, :label => "Name"
      f.input :image, :as => :file, :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url(:medium))
      f.input :details, :input_html => { :class => 'autogrow', :rows => 5, :cols => 30, :maxlength => 10  }
      f.input :start_datetime
      f.input :end_datetime
      f.input :location, :input_html => { :class => 'autogrow', :rows => 5, :cols => 30, :maxlength => 10  }
      f.input :gmap_lattitude
      f.input :gmap_logitude
      f.input :email
      f.input :mobile
      f.input :website
    end
    f.buttons
  end

  index do
    column :name
    column :user
    column :city
    column :status
    column :start_datetime
#    column :end_datetime
    column :email
    default_actions
  end

  show do |event|
    attributes_table do
      row :name
      row :details
      row :user
      row :city
      row :status do event.status.titleize end
      # has_many :through
      row :themes do
        event.themes.collect{|t| t.name}.join(', ')
      end
      row :event_type do
        event.event_types.collect{|t| t.name}.join(', ')
      end
      row :start_datetime
      row :end_datetime
      row :location
      row :gmap_lattitude
      row :gmap_logitude
      row :email
      row :mobile
      row :created_at
      row :updated_at

    end
    active_admin_comments
  end

end
```

**EDIT**
There are a few themes available

https://github.com/vigetlabs/active_material

https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_theme

https://github.com/paladini/activeadmin-themes

Comment: You can add also `actions :index, :new, :create`.

Comment: @pravin, this is wonderful! Thank you for taking the time to do this it helps out a lot!